# Can't align vertically a .swf file to the middle

Tags: javascript, html, css, flash, dreamweaver

I inserted a .swf file to my page inside a div, and I tried to make it vertically aligned to the middle of this div, but it didn't work, only horizontally but that's not what I want.
I tried to place this file in another div inside the main div and change the alignment of this div as well.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Suggestions? Yes. Instead of repeating the word 'div' five times, post the code you've tried.

Comment: I used it and it didn't work either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a good way I use to center elements horizontally and vertically:

```
<div style="position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;">  
  <div style="height:100%; display:table; margin:0 auto;">  
    <div style="vertical-align:middle; display:table-cell;">

    <div><p>This is a fully-centered div!</p></div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe it works in all browsers as well! and not a problem =]

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... its kinda hard to answer without a code snippet.

Here is an article for creating wrappers around Flash content: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=wrapper_13.html

Scroll down to the table, where they start talking about "align" or just do a page search for the word "align" to see what they have to say.

Here is also a quick idea, I have noooo idea whether or not it works, just food for thought:

```
div.SWFContainer object, div.SWFContainer embed {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto 0px auto 0px;
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```